# Enter chamar Button no Google Chrome e Firefox

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Preciso que quando o usuário apertar a tecla enter, faça o evento de click do button.
Estou fazendo desta forma, porém não está funcionando no Google Chrome e nem no firefox:

```html
     if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                txtsenha.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {document.getElementById('"+btnEntrar.UniqueID+"').click();return false;}} else {return true}; ");
            }
```

Tentei também colocando desta forma abaixo, porém também não funciona no Google Chrome e no firefox.

```html
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnEntrar">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Empresa" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Código da Empresa"></asp:TextBox>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <button class="fa fa-industry" style="background: transparent; border: none"></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdent" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Identificador"></asp:TextBox>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <button class="fa fa-user fa-lg" style="background: transparent; border: none"></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtsenha" class="form-control" runat="server" type="password" placeholder="Senha" AutoPostBack="False" OnTextChanged="txtsenha_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <button class="fa fa-unlock-alt fa-lg" style="background: transparent; border: none"></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />

                        <asp:Button ID="btnEntrar" runat="server" Text="Entrar " CssClass="radius" OnClick="btnEntrar_Click" />
                    </asp:Panel>
```

Fiz essa adaptação no código, porém também nada acontece.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#txtsenha').on('keypress', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == '13') {
                    jQuery('#btnEntrar').trigger('click');
                }
            })

            jQuery('#btnEntrar').click(function () {
                alert('Click!');
            });

        });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtsenha" class="form-control" runat="server" type="password" placeholder="Senha" AutoPostBack="False" OnTextChanged="txtsenha_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <button class="fa fa-unlock-alt fa-lg" style="background: transparent; border: none"></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEntrar" runat="server" Text="Entrar " CssClass="radius" OnClick="btnEntrar_Click" />
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a propriedade DefaultButton="myButton" ?

Leia mais aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638119/how-to-set-a-default-enter-on-a-certain-button

Comment: Estou tentando dessa forma também, porém nada acontece.

Comment: Poste o seu código da aspx para ver se eu consigo te ajudar.

Comment: Alterei incluindo o código Aspx, obrigado.

Comment: Realmente não consegui ver porque não funciona. Dê uma lida neste link para ver se ajuda: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17241/Capturing-the-Enter-key-to-cause-a-button-click#_comments

Comment: Jhonathan eu verifiquei o problema está nos navegadores Google Chrome e no Firefox. No IE funciona normal. Porém eu precisava que funcionasse em todos estes navegadores. Vou ver este link q me passou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, com este código. Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.

```html
 if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                txtsenha.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {document.getElementById('" + btnEntrar.ClientID + "').click();return false;}} else {return true}; ");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo um exemplo funcional utilizando jQuery.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#senha').on('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == '13'){
      jQuery('#entrar').trigger('click');
    }
  })
  
  jQuery('#entrar').click(function(){
    alert('Click!');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="senha" id="senha" value="" type="password">
<input type="button" value="entrar" name="entrar" id="entrar">
```

Comment: Esse exemplo funciona em todos os navegadores? Adaptei a função para o meu projeto, porém não funciona.

Comment: Pode postar seu código adaptado ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código adaptado.